# if conditional for counting "1" digits in a string not executing

Tags: c++, string, if-statement

I have to do a comparison between every bit of a binary string and 1; if the bit is 1 then increment a counter by 1.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <cstdio>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <bits/stdc++.h>
#include <algorithm>

using namespace std;

int main(int argc, char const *argv[])
{
    int n, d;
    cin >> n >> d;
    string a1("1");
    int count = 0;
    int sum[1000];
    string a[1000];
    for (int i = 0; i < d; i++) {
        cin >> a[i];
        for (int j = 0; j < n; j++) {

            if (a[j].compare(a1) == 0) {
                count++;
            }
        }
        sum[i] = count;
        cout << sum[i] << endl;
    }
    int kill = 0;

    for (int i = 0; i < d; i++) {
        if (sum[i] == 0) {
            kill++;
        } else if (sum[i] == sum[i + 1]) {
            kill++;
        }
    }

    //cout<<kill<<endl;

    return 0;
}
```

I have written this logic, but the `if` conditional isn't working, as it should execute when `a[j]` is 1, but it's not.

How can I do this correctly?

Comment: Did you debug it? I assume no. So please go do that and watch your variables and your loop counters to monitor what is exactly happening on every iteration.

Comment: Your question is lacking since you gave no real background about the logic.  And using a debugger would get you more help than just dumping your code here.

Comment: It sounds like you may need to learn how to use a debugger to step through your code. With a good debugger, you can execute your program line by line and see where it is deviating from what you expect. This is an essential tool if you are going to do any programming.  Further reading: **[How to debug small programs](http://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/)**

Comment: Think about what you're comparing in `a[j].compare(a1) == 0` (which is the same as `a[j] == a1`, and in what way `a[j]` has anything to do with the string you just read into `a[i]`.

Comment: Actually, I wanted to compare every bit of my input string with 1, so that's why I was doing this, is it right way ?

Comment: @YashJain I thought my comment was an obvious hint that it's not the right way. (More hints: A string is made up of characters. You don't want to compare to the string `"1"`, you want to compare to the character `'1'`.)

Comment: you want to do     if(a[i][j] == '1') , also in the loop you would want to check for length of string and n as that way you can input lesser bits

Comment: I did comparedit with '1' but it's again giving me error. nvalid conversion from ‘char’ to ‘const char*’ [-fpermissive]
    if(a[j].compare('1') == 0){

Comment: You can also make the code a *little* more readable, by inserting comments to explain major statements.

Comment: @YashJain That's not a sign that '1' is wrong, it's a sign that you're comparing the wrong thing to '1'.

Comment: Sorry @molbdnilo I am not getting what you're trying to say. What's the problem if I have store "1" in string OR '1' in char variable and then comparing it by every bit ?

Comment: @YashJain There are no "bits" - you have read a string of characters, `a[i]`. At the moment you're comparing an entire string (and it's not even the string you just read) to the string `"1"`. You should compare *each character* in the string (`a[i]`) you read to the character `'1'`.  (I think you've confused yourself by unnecessarily making `a` an array of strings.)

Answer (score 0):

Try using `strcmp()` instead of `compare`.

```
if (strcmp(a[j], a1) == 0)
{
    count++;
}
```